# show and hide a portlet when clicking on a link inside another portlet

Tags: java, liferay, icefaces

I have three portlets for example: `portletA`, `portletB` and `portletC`.

`portletA` displays on left side and it has two links `linkB` and `linkC`.

If I click on `linkB` then `portletB` should be displayed on right side and If I click on `linkC` then `portletB` must become hidden and `portletC` should be displayed.

Please, tell me how I can do this using [ICEfaces](http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEfaces/overview.jsf).

Answer (score 2):

I used this code to hide the portlet but after refreshing the page again portlet is visible can you suggest what I can do so that after refreshing portlet should not visible?

```
       function fun(E)
       {

           if(E=="Entry")
               {
           alert("hi");

                 document.getElementById("p_p_id_ipc_WAR_IPC2portlet_").style.display='none';
                 document.getElementById("p_p_id_ipc1_WAR_IPC2portlet_").style.display = '';



               }

           else
               {
               alert("else");
               }

           }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple javascript and css. What you have to do is see what portlet B and C portlet id's are and than using javascript you can alter css "display" property on the portlet boundary div.

Using simple javascript

```
var p = document.getElementById("p_p_id_YOUR-PORTLET-ID_");
if (p) {
  if (p.style.display == "none") {
    p.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    p.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Using jQuery

```
jQuery("p_p_id_YOUR-PORTLET-ID_").show();
//or
jQuery("p_p_id_YOUR-PORTLET-ID_").hide();
```

Examples are for showing/hiding single portlet. In your case link B should hide C and show B, and link C other way around.

Also take a look at [Client-side Inter-Portlet Communication](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Client-side+Inter-Portlet+Communication)